# Issue with jQueryUI Slider (range)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the same page:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/rangemin.html

I use: `<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" />`

When I wrote: `<?php echo $_POST['amount'] ?>` I get: **0**

Any help to fix this issue? Thank in advance.

Comment: How are you posting?  That page doesn't have a `<form>` and such

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need an empty `value=""` before you fill in the value with the jQuery before you post.